# Discord bot access online spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, spreadsheet

Where would I even begin to have a discord bot access an online spreadsheet?

I'm in the process of coding a bot that does multiple tasks, but have yet to come across anything in regards to this.

Answer (score 1):

The flow is going to be interaction with your bot and your bot interacting with some REST API. I assume you are aiming for something like Google Sheets. So you will have to wrap interaction with your bot into interaction with Sheets API. Further help is almost impossible as exact goal was not specified.

Here is documentation for Google Sheets:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Here is documentation for discord.js:
https://discord.js.org

For interaction with Google Sheets, Google has made their own ?framework? for working with Google Workspace products called Google Apps Script. You can use this to introduce further automation into those products, but in your case I doubt you will need to use it.

Link to App Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script